# Laravel Blade does not include css and .js present in template

Tags: laravel-5.1

I need, from a view-blade, to search a database in order to fetch data and display them in another view-blade when a link is clicked.

I made the following:

In the view-blade who will acting on database:

```
@foreach($pending as $p)
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="{{ route('openMyPage', $p->ident ) }}">Click here</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

the connected 'route' is

```
Route::get("/getMyForm/{ident}", ['as' => "openMyPage", 'uses' => "BusinessController@seeMyForm"]);
```

the method on BusinessController has

```
public function seeMyForm($ident){
$myResult=DB::select(...);
return view('MyViewBlade')->with('myResult', $myResult);
}
```

the master template (PrincipalView.blade.php) (as was included in the view-blade to display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">              
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css"> -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>  

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> -->

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>      
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-pessoal.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-pessoal2.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/multiple-select-master/multiple-select.css"></script>       
    <script src="assets/plugins/multiple-select-master/multiple-select.js"></script> 

    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
...
    <div class="container">


        @yield("corpo")


    </div>
...
```

the view-blade which will display (ToAproveView.blade.php)

```
@extends('PrincipalView')
@section('corpo')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Cliente Principal: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="idTxtFaturamentoAprovacaoCliente" 
name="namTxtFaturamentoAprovacaoCliente" 
readonly  value="{{$myResult[0]->clienteprincipal}}"/>

    </div>  
</div>
```

is not working. The last view-blade do not render its elements. The view opens itself not well formatted.

Other actions make all other views-blade ok.

I found out, the problem is connected with the line code

```
 <a href="{{ route('openMyPage', $p->ident ) }}">Click here</a>
```

because it was created on the fly (I guess).

Looking at the console of Chrome, is there

```
GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css 
29638_1472048778961_121:16 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css 
29638_1472048778961_121:18 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/js/jquery.js 
29638_1472048778961_121:13 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css 
29638_1472048778961_121:22 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js 
 29638_1472048778961_121:28 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
29638_1472048778961_121:29 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
29638_1472048778961_121:23 GET http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

The including css and js files do not work (the names in the path are different of that I was wrote abore because I made a translation to better comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the error is.
I changed the path to .js and css files in default template and the view rendered correctly:

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Although there is not the correct answer, since this template serves several views-blade that work perfectly, for now it is ok to me.